# How to build the first User , with an invitation list model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I am trying to use invitations for my site . I want to know that ; My first User can't need an invitation ? How can I make an exception? I can guess that , 
I must use a rescue exception but I dont know where it must be done?
My users.rb model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :nickname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :invitation_token
  has_secure_password
  has_many :friendships
    has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
    has_many :inverse_friendships, :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
    has_many :inverse_friends, :through => :inverse_friendships, :source => :user

  has_many :topics, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  before_save { |user| user.nickname = nickname.downcase }
  before_save :create_remember_token

  validates :nickname, presence: true, length: { maximum: 150 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true,
                                        format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                                        uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false }

    validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

    validates_presence_of :invitation_id, :message => 'gerekli'
    validates_uniqueness_of :invitation_id
    has_many :sent_invitations, :class_name => 'Invitation', :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
    belongs_to :invitation

    before_create :set_invitation_limit

    def invitation_token
        invitation.token if invitation
    end

    def invitation_token=(token)
        self.invitation = Invitation.find_by_token(token)
    end

    private

    def create_remember_token
        self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end

    def set_invitation_limit
        self.invitation_limit = 5
    end
end
```

And this is the users_controller.rb:

```
def new
  @user = User.new(:invitation_token => params[:invitation_token])
  @user.email = @user.invitation.recipient_email if @user.invitation
end

   def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Giripedia'ya hoşgeldiniz'!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a conditional validation. Let me give you a short example:

```
class User
  # ...
  validates_presence_of :invitation_id, :if => :invitation_needed?

  # An invitation is needed if there is at least one user. If there
  # are no users, there can't be an invitation.
  def invitation_needed?
    User.all.count >= 1
  end
end
```

Details: See the manual on [conditional validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#conditional-validation)

Comment: I resetted db.When I want to create first user ,The message is: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.invitation_id: SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."invitation_id" IS NULL LIMIT 1

Comment: Then you probably deleted your database table. Run `rake db:migrate` to fix that.

Comment: yes I migrated again. I think I have written exceptions code not in the controller. Trying to solve.

Comment: No , I can't get the first User to create.

Comment: Is there an invitation_id column in your table?

Comment: Yes, I added t.integer  "invitation",
    t.integer  "invitation_limit" ... Shall i make default false?

Comment: Use `t.integer "invitation_id"` instead of `t.integer "invitation"`. The column should be named `invitation_id`, not `invitation`.

Comment: I changed "invitation_id" .. still I get the same error for the initial User.

Comment: Did you run `rake db:drop` and `rake db:migrate` afterwards to actually change the name of the column?

Comment: Yes .. somehow passenger didnot stop so that's why it was not working. Thank you it works now.

Answer (score 1):

I m not sure if this is a good idea to write a conditional validation just to be able to save your first user.

You dont want to do a count query every time you are validating a user.

You can save your first user from console with skip validation option.

```
@user.save(:validate => false)
```

Comment: Merhaba , ben de yeni başladım ruby on railse cevap için teşekkürler.